# FB.login in Chrome app / webview

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-webview

I'm trying to package our current web-app into a desktop Chrome app, and am using a single-line webview in window.html

```
<webview src="http://seevl.fm" style="width:1100px; height:720px"></webview>
```

The web-app uses FB.login() [1] and works well in the browser, yet, I have the following message when using it in the Chrome app

```
<webview>: A new window was blocked.
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong. The FB.login() action is triggered by a user-click.

Is there any permissions required?

Thanks

[1] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

NB: Cross-posted on Chromium Apps Google groups

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?  I've been unable to get links to open in a new tab/window as well.

Answer (score 0):

In a Chrome App, you should use chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow() to authenticate with Facebook (see http://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow).